# Can we include form in another form in C# window application just like web application?

Tags: c#, forms, window

I want the functionality of adding form in another form just like we include files or use master page in ASP.Net web application.

Is there any alternative of master page or include files for C# window application?

Right bar in my window application will contain the buttons that will be same for almost every form. For this, I need the alternative of master page in C# window application.

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you're using winforms?

Comment: Make your "master page" a form and derive other forms from there. It is called inheritance.

Comment: Well you can try with by inheriting a form and then adding the controls required to your inherited form

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are trying to do is possible. It is a good thing you described the reason why you want it. And for that, C#.NET WinForms has the possibility to inherit forms.

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx1155fz.aspx

It works very well, I use it all the time.